wire:model value not accessible during x-init for x-modelable properties
I have the following component
<div>
    <div
        x-data="{ value: 0 }"
        x-modelable="value"
        wire:model.live="counter"
        x-init="console.log('init', value)" // value prints 0 on init. Livewire is set to $counter = 5
    >
        <button x-on:click="value--" type="button" class="border border-gray-600 rounded-full h-8 w-8 flex justify-center items-center hover:bg-gray-100">-</button>
        <button x-on:click="value++" type="button" class="border border-gray-600 rounded-full h-8 w-8 flex justify-center items-center hover:bg-gray-100">+</button>
    </div>

    {{ $counter }}
</div>

In PHP, $counter = 5
The counter works all as expected. value is set to 5, the buttons move the counter both on Alpine and Livewire side up and down.
The only issue, is that during x-init, console.log prints value = 0. This is the starting value and not the wire:model value.
Without getting the wire:model value at this stage, you are unable to do things like set starting content on a markdown editor using the init function.
Is this a limitation where we need to continue using $wire.entangle, or is there another way?

@entangle is still a valid option, however, if you want to keep separate variables between Alpine and Livewire you can simply initialize the value variable to $wire.counter instead of 0:
<div>
    <div x-data="{ value: $wire.counter }"
         x-modelable="value"
         wire:model.live="counter"
         x-init="console.log('init', value)"
    >
        <button x-on:click="value--"
                type="button"
                class="border border-gray-600 rounded-full h-8 w-8 flex justify-center items-center hover:bg-gray-100"
        >
           -
        </button>

        <button x-on:click="value++"
                type="button"
                class="border border-gray-600 rounded-full h-8 w-8 flex justify-center items-center hover:bg-gray-100"
        >
           +
        </button>

        Livewire counter: [ {{ $counter }} ]

        <br>

        <div>
            Alpine counter: [
            <span x-text="value"></span>
            ]
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

